# XSLT how to ignore {} characters

Tags: xslt

I am creating an xsl file.
I want to print below code as output

```
<li class="td-nav-flyout {position:'containerleft'}">
```

But when I run the code java says "cannot compile stylesheet".

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

-Ritesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the xsl:attribute element?

```
<li>
   <xsl:attribute name="class">td-nav-flyout {position:'containerleft'}</xsl:attribute>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
<li class="td-nav-flyout {{position:'containerleft'}}">
```

Normally, the curly braces inside attribute text allow you to evaluate XPath expressions. See [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in the spec for full information.